# Submit form only after confirm it in the modal using react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

**Can't submit react-hook-form on confirm in modal component. I need directly submit if user select confirm.

Tried to write modal inside FormSubmitButton. Also I tried inside form component but always I can submit after I confirmed modal then modal closed and then I should push submit again and it submitting.
**
This is FormSubmit component:

```
import { Svg } from "@/components/Svg";
import { Box, Button, ButtonProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";

import type { FieldValues, FormState } from "react-hook-form";

export type FormSubmitButtonProps<FV extends FieldValues> = ButtonProps & {
  formState: FormState<FV>;
  folder?: string;
  iconName?: string;
  wide?: boolean;
};

const FormSubmitButton = <FV extends FieldValues>({
  folder,
  iconName,
  name,
  formState,
  wide,
  ...props
}: FormSubmitButtonProps<FV>) => {
  const { isSubmitting } = formState;

  return (
    <Button
      type="submit"
      isLoading={isSubmitting}
      isDisabled={isSubmitting}
      {...props}
    >
      {!wide && folder && iconName && (
        <Box mr="8px">
          <Svg folder={folder} iconName={iconName} />
        </Box>
      )}
      {name}
      {wide && folder && iconName && (
        <Box ml="8px">
          <Svg folder={folder} iconName={iconName} />
        </Box>
      )}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default FormSubmitButton;
```

This is form component where I using FormSubmitButton component:

```
import { FC, useState } from "react";
import { VStack, HStack, Stack } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { IconButton } from "@/components/IconButton";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import { createInputList } from "@/components/form";
import { LeftFormSection } from "./LeftFormSection";
import { RightFormSection } from "./RightFormSection";
import { UserSchemaType } from "../NewUser";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { useAccountPasswordCreate } from "@/api/queries/account";
import { ConfirmationModal } from "@/components/ConfirmationModal";

const { FormSubmitButton } = createInputList<UserSchemaType>();

export const UserForm: FC = () => {
  const { formState, reset, getValues } = useFormContext<UserSchemaType>();
  const { id: UserId } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  const { isDirty } = formState;

  const [showClearConfirmation, setShowClearConfirmation] = useState(false);

  const [showPasswordConfirmation, setShowPasswordConfirmation] =
    useState(false);

  const { mutate: passwordCreate } = useAccountPasswordCreate();

  const email = getValues("email");

  const handleNewPassword = () => {
    passwordCreate({ data: { email } });
  };

  const handleResetForm = () => {
    reset();
  };
  const handleClearConfirmation = () => {
    setShowClearConfirmation(true);
  };
  const handleClearConfirmationCancel = () => {
    setShowClearConfirmation(false);
  };
  const handleClearConfirmationConfirm = () => {
    handleResetForm();
  };

  const handlePasswordConfirmationConfirm = async () => {
    handleNewPassword();
    setShowPasswordConfirmation(false);
  };

  const handlePasswordConfirmation = () => {
    setShowPasswordConfirmation(true);
  };
  const handlePasswordConfirmationCancel = () => {
    setShowPasswordConfirmation(false);
  };

  return (
    <VStack
      bg="white"
      borderRadius="24px"
      w={{ base: "full", md: "1130px" }}
      maxW={{ base: "full", md: "1130px" }}
      p="40px"
    >
      <Stack
        gap={4}
        alignItems="flex-start"
        w="full"
        flexDir={{ base: "column", md: "row" }}
      >
        <LeftFormSection />
        <RightFormSection />
      </Stack>
      <HStack
        data-testid="form-footer"
        w="full"
        justifyContent="flex-end"
        pt={4}
      >
        <IconButton
          name="Zrušit"
          folder="menu"
          iconName="close"
          variant="outline"
          colorScheme="darkGray"
          onClick={handleClearConfirmation}
        />
        {UserId && (
          <IconButton
            folder="menu"
            iconName="edit"
            colorScheme="darkGray"
            variant="outline"
            name="Nové heslo"
            onClick={handlePasswordConfirmation}
          />
        )}
        <FormSubmitButton
          name="Uložit"
          iconName="ulozhit"
          folder="menu"
          formState={formState}
          isDisabled={!isDirty}
        />
      </HStack>
      <ConfirmationModal
        isOpen={showPasswordConfirmation}
        onClose={handlePasswordConfirmationCancel}
        onConfirm={handlePasswordConfirmationConfirm}
        title={"Jste si jisti, že chcete změnit heslo?"}
        message={"Tímto aktem změníte heslo uživatele. Jste si jisti?"}
        confirmButtonText={"Ano, změnit heslo"}
        cancelButtonText="Zrušit"
      />
      <ConfirmationModal
        isOpen={showClearConfirmation}
        onClose={handleClearConfirmationCancel}
        onConfirm={handleClearConfirmationConfirm}
        title="Jasné potvrzení formuláře"
        message="Jste si jisti, že chcete formulář vymazat?"
        confirmButtonText="Ano, čirá"
        cancelButtonText="Zrušit"
      />
    </VStack>
  );
};
```

And this is my ConfirmationModal component:

```
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalContent,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalOverlay,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { FC } from "react";

interface ConfirmationModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: VoidFunction;
  onConfirm: VoidFunction;
  title: string;
  message: string;
  confirmButtonText: string;
  cancelButtonText: string;
}

export const ConfirmationModal: FC<ConfirmationModalProps> = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  onConfirm,
  title,
  message,
  confirmButtonText,
  cancelButtonText,
}) => {
  const handleConfirm = () => {
    onConfirm();
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
      <ModalOverlay />
      <ModalContent>
        <ModalHeader>{title}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>{message}</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button colorScheme="red" mr={3} onClick={handleConfirm}>
            {confirmButtonText}
          </Button>
          <Button variant="ghost" onClick={onClose}>
            {cancelButtonText}
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </ModalContent>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it just fix previous mistake when I tried to trigger submit on confirm. So the problem was that I call handleSubmit(onSubmit) <== like this. But need to call like this ==> handleSubmit(onSubmit)(). So final solution looks:

```
const [showSubmitConfirmation, setShowSubmitConfirmation] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmitConfirmationConfirm = () => {
    handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
    setShowSubmitConfirmation(false);
  };

  const handleSubmitConfirmation = () => {
    setShowSubmitConfirmation(true);
  };

  const handleSubmitConfirmationCancel = () => {
    setShowSubmitConfirmation(false);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSubmitConfirmation)}>
      <HStack w="full" h="full" spacing="68px">
        <UserForm />
        <ConfirmationModal
          isOpen={showSubmitConfirmation}
          onClose={handleSubmitConfirmationCancel}
          onConfirm={handleSubmitConfirmationConfirm}
          title="Jste si jisti, že chcete aktualizovat?"
          message="Potvrzením aktualizujete. Jste si jisti?"
          confirmButtonText="Ano, aktualizovat"
          cancelButtonText="Zrušit"
        />
      </HStack>
    </form>
  );
```